# Throwing coin 6 times, probability to get H is 1/3. what is the probability to get H in 2 first throws?

Tags: probability

A question from a previous exam:

> Throwing a coin 6 times, a coin which has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ to get `H`.
>
> What is the probability that the 2 first throws will give `H`, when given that there's exactly 4 `H`s?

I know it's a basic question but I didn't practiced probability  too much time.

Please give me the idea and the approach, but not the final answer.

thank you so much

## EDIT

attempt:

Said:

$$P(\text{First two Heads}|\text{4 total Heads}) = \frac{P(\text{First 2 heads AND total 4 Heads})}{P(\text{total of 4 Heads})} $$

Well,

Let A be `2 first throws are H`. any permutation of `(H,H, .., .., .., ..)`, $\implies P = 4! = 24$

Let B be `exactly 4 Hs`, so: $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ (how many combinations with exactly 4 Hs?)

Now $B \cap A$ will be all permutations such that: $(H, H, \text{*another 2 Hs*})$, so: $\binom{4}{2}$ = 6.

Which leads to: $\frac{6}{15} = \frac{2}{5}$. is this correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Comment: You are close but you are making an assumption that all outcomes are equivalent, which they aren't since $P(H) = \frac13$

Comment: @jameselmore Where should I use that fact?

Comment: @jameselmore:  but all outcomes with exactly four heads have the same probability

Comment: Yes, your $2/5$ is correct

Comment: Yeap, when all outcomes *within* the condition are *equally probable* their weights cancel and you just need to count favoured outcomes verses total outcomes (for the condition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote an event of a sequence of $4$ heads and $2$ tails in any order.   This is the conditioning event.

Let $B$ denote an event of any sequence that starts with $2$ heads.   This is the favoured event.

Then $A\cap B$ is an event of a sequence of $4$ heads and $2$ tails that starts with $2$ heads.   This is the joint event.

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A) & =\binom 6 4 \cdot \color{blue}{\left(\frac 1 3\right)^4\cdot\left(1-\frac 1 3\right)^2} 
\\[1ex] & =\dfrac{20}{243}
\\[4ex]
\mathsf P(A\cap B) & =\binom 4 2 \cdot \color{blue}{\left(\frac13\right)^4\cdot\left(1-\frac 1 3\right)^2}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{ 8}{243}
\\[4ex]
\mathsf P(B\mid A) & =\dfrac{\mathsf P({A}\cap{B})}{\mathsf P(A)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\frac{8}{243}}{\frac{20}{243}}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{2}{5}
\end{align}$$

---

**Remark** Notice the common terms.  *Because* the atomic outcomes within the condition are all equally probable, then their probability weights cancel and we *can* just compare the numbers of outcomes.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(B\mid A) & = \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{2}} 
\\[1ex] & = \frac 2 5
\end{align}$$

Comment: $B$ should denote an event of any sequence starting with 2 heamds.  $A\cap B$ is the event of 4 heads and 2 tails starting with 2 heads.  Then we have: $\mathsf P(A\cap B) = 8/243$ and $\mathsf P(B\mid A) = 2/5$, as desired (the probability of starting with 2 heads given that 4 heads and 2 tails occur.)

Comment: @GrahamKemp: B should denote whatever event you want it to denote, as long as it allows you to solve the question at hand correctly. If you see anything in my solution which is not correct, then please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: P.S., I do admit that choosing B according to your advice would eliminate the "$\frac{P({B}\cap{A})}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$" part, which might be confusing, as it is the case only due to my choice of B. So feel free to edit it if you think that it will improve the answer and contribute to the website :)

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$P(\text{First two Heads}|\text{4 total Heads}) = \frac{P(\text{First 2 heads AND total 4 Heads})}{P(\text{total of 4 Heads})} $$

In general, $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \text{ and }B)}{P(B)}$$

Comment: Thank you, can you please look at my update?